# How to check if there is any instance of a class at runtime?

Tags: java

Is there any method to check whether any instance of a class is running?

I have a GUI and I don't want open another instance of it, if a one is already running.
I know about including a counter in constructor. Any method except that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could make your GUI a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any method to check whether any instance of a class is running?

The simple answer is No.

The normal way to deal with this problem is to use the Singleton design pattern.  The idea of the pattern is that you write the code to *remove the possibility* of creating multiple instance of the class.

In Java you typically do this by declaring the class constructor to be private, and providing access to the singleton instance via a static method.  Depending on your precise requirements, the singleton can be created eagerly or lazily.

Bohemian's answer provides a good example of this approach.

(In Java 5 or later, it is also possible to use `enum` types to implement singletons.)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Here is a simple implementation in java of a singleton:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass INSTANCE = new MyClass();

    private MyClass() { // private constructor prevents creation outside class
    }

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Note that this is not "bulletproof" (there are "hacks" you can use via reflection to circumvent this and create two instances), however if you're the only user of the code it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Enum as recommended by J. Bloch (Effective Java Programming 2nd Ed., Addison Wesley)